# How does http://to./ work?

Tags: domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How the heck is http://to./ a valid domain name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/90737/how-the-heck-is-http-to-a-valid-domain-name)

http://to./ must be the shortest domain name I have ever seen. How can did they register a domain without an extension?

Comment: There's already a question on Serverfault and it really belongs there...but it will get closed as duplicate there...a moral conundrum...

Comment: duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/90737/how-the-heck-is-http-to-a-valid-domain-name

Answer (score 1):

They didn't, they have a top level domain (.to) - http://www.to/ is them (when entering http://to./your browser automatically inserted the www. part and the trailing . prevented your browser from adding .com

Comment: -1 The browser doesn't insert anything. It send a DNS request for the domain "to", whick correspond to 216.74.32.103.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/to.html

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you are mistaken?

`$ whois to.`

`No whois server is known for this kind of object.`