# The to. top level domain

Tags: domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How the heck is to./ a valid domain name?](https://serverfault.com/questions/90737/how-the-heck-is-http-to-a-valid-domain-name)

How is http://to./ a valid domain?

It's the only thing I've ever seen with '.' as the last character in the domain name.

Ping won't even hit it.

Are there any other examples of domains like this?

Comment: Dennis is right.  Follow that link for some rather good explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name

The . you are questioning is a red herring.  All domains should have them on the end but they are generally left off.

http://www.to/ and http://www.to./ are the same

http://to./ I think must be a shortcut in the browser because you can type it in the address bar but not link to it

Comment: Adding the "." after the domain is so your local computer doesn't try to search it as a hostname in your local domain (or configured search domains).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com./ is one. Seriously though you can add a dot to the end of any DNS name I am impressed they worked something out with Tonga, but they have always been on the cutting edge of selling their domain